# How can I create a dynamic feature file in Cucumber?

Tags: automated-testing, test-automation-framework, cucumber

I have knowledge about static feature file and it is tough to handle for test case. I want to create dynamic feature file or dynamic content for test case in feature file.

Comment: What do you mean by "dynamic"? User input / data fetching from external in during run-time or data-driven testing?

Comment: Welcome here. Please have a look into [asking a question](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/help/asking). As it stands your question is rather vague. What did you try? What did you research?

Comment: @JoãoFarias I have created 1 automation script in cucumber and you know feature file is important in it. In feature file, I have written 4 features test case and execute it. Now I want to execute only 2 features test case so I need to remove or make comment in feature file.

I have created jar file to execute cucumber test run. So I need to execute feature file from externally.

Comment: Got it. See my anwser below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cucumber has options called "tags", which allows you for filter scenarios and run just a subset.

[Here](http://toolsqa.com/selenium-cucumber-framework/run-cucumber-test-from-command-line-terminal/), you have instructions on how to run Cucumber tests using Maven:

```
mvn test -Dcucumber.options=”–tags @tag Example”
```

will run only scenarios with the *@Example* tags.